# What are the Apple-provided drivers for the AMD Pro Vega 16/20 for Windows 10?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, driver

For those who own a 2018/2019 MacBook Pro with AMD Pro Vega 16/20 video cards - what are the Apple-provided drivers that come with Boot Camp? Are those video cards supported under Windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Yes, they are supported in Windows. The **Windows Support** image which gets downloaded from `Boot Camp Assistant.app` if you are on a 2018/2019 MBP shows AMD drivers. These can be downloaded manually using the [brigadier tool](https://github.com/timsutton/brigadier), by specifying the correct model name (*e.g.* `MacBookPro15,3`).